# window properties for new window while using target = new in jsp / anchor

Tags: jsp, new-operator, target

I am launching a third party website on clicking an anchor, what I want is to open the new website in a new window on click of an anchor (here using netui framework) and the new window should have disabled address bar and specific window size...
is it possible to have anything like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.open()` is what you need. It offers some options with the third parameter. http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Comment: window.open is good but here we are generationg parameters on the click only so window.open wont work dynamically :(

Comment: @sij: Why not? The third parameter is a string. You can concatenate whatever options you want to set and then call `window.open()` with it.

Comment: @sjngm : one more doubt please , consider the scenario i am clicking a button on this button i am goin to an action, the forward from this action has to go to the new window and this new window should have the required properties, can you now direct me, and what happens first the on click or the java action ???

Comment: @sij: the `onclick` of the button would probably do something like `window.open("http://host.wherever.com/my/path/something.do", "newChildWindow", "location=0");`. In other words you are calling the new page in the new window already.